# ctrl alt supr en anydesk ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

Estoy intentando iniciar sesión remota sobre un ordenador con windows, sin embargo al intentar desbloquear el equipo necesito usar ctrl + alt + supr, pero tengo deshabilitada la opción en el menú de anydesk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo habilitar esta opción en ubuntu? Ya que intenté ejecutar AnyDesk como usuario root y no es posible.

Answer (score 2):

AnyDesk tiene que estar instalado en el equipo remoto (en este caso, en el equipo con Windows) para que esté disponible la opción de enviarle ctrl + alt + supr

Está explicado en https://support.anydesk.com/Session_Settings

> Ctrl + Alt + Del: Invokes the secure attention sequence on the remote
> machine (pressing these keys cannot be transmitted directly by
> AnyDesk, as the operating system does not permit it for security
> reasons). **This option is only available if AnyDesk is installed on the
> remote Windows machine**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he leído esa explicación no solo en el sitio de anydesk, sino en varios foros, pero realmente no la comprendo, el equipo de windows tiene instalado anydesk, de lo contrario no podría controlarlo, no? O es que hay que instalarlo de alguna manera específica ?

Comment: Se puede "ejecutar el programa" y permitir el acceso remoto sin haber hecho la instalación. En el equipo "host", cuando "el cliente" se desconecta, muestra la opción de instalarlo permanentemente o bien, cerrarlo y no modificar nada.